# Artin-Schreier theorem for rings (a little different)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, field-extensions

**Motivation:**
Let me recall the well-known Artin-Schreier theorem (AST) for fields in a non-formal way; if $L$ is an algebraically closed field, and $K \subset L$ a subfield not 'much smaller' than $L$, then the AST describes precisely what forms $K$ can have.

**Setting:**
Now imagine the following situation; we start with

- an integral domain $R$,
- let $K$ be the quotient field of $R$,
- and denote by $\bar{K}$ some fixed algebraic closure of $K$.

If $\mathcal{O}$ denotes the integral closure of $R$ in $\bar{K}$, then one can easily show, that the quotient field of $\mathcal{O}$ is $\bar{K}$.

**Question:**
In the 'spirit' of the AST, my question is, if $K$ is already algebraically closed, does it mean, that there is no proper integral extension of $R$? In other words, if $S/R$ is integral, then $S = R$?

**My attempt(s):** I can only guess; so far I have failed in coming up with a proof. I do not really know where in the proof I can use that $K$ is algebraically closed. My guess would be, that if there is an 'counter-example', i.e. there exists a proper integral extension of $R$, than it must be difficult to construct.

Comment: In your question, I assume that you want $R$ to be integrally closed in $K$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MannyReyes I am sorry if my question was not stated clearly enough. That is exactly the point, that I am **not** assuming $R$ to be integrally closed; yet I am assuming that $K$, the quotient field of $R$, be algebraically closed. My question is, if $R$ is then necessarily normal.

Comment: What I meant by the spirit of the AST: if $R$ is a domain, such that its quotient field $K$ is algebraically closed (this means, $R$ is not 'much smaller' than the *absolute integral closure*), must $R$ be already the absolute integral closure itself?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you intended for $R$ to already be integrally closed in $K$, i.e. normal. Then the answer to your question is yes.

**Claim:** Suppose the domain $R$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions $K$. If $S/R$ is an integral extension of domains, then $S = R$.

**Proof:** First note that the field of fractions $L$ of $S$ is an extension field of $K$. Because $K$ is algebraically closed and  $S$ is integral (over $R$ and thus) over $K$, we in fact have $R \subseteq S \subseteq K \subseteq L$.

Given $s \in S$, let $p(x) \in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $s$ over $K$. Because $s$ is integral over $R$, [it follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292638/an-element-is-integral-iff-its-minimal-polynomial-has-integral-coefficients) that $p(x) \in R[x]$. But since $S \subseteq K$, $p(x)$ must have degree 1. So we must have $$p(x) = x - s \in R[x].$$ Thus $s \in R$, which shows that $S = R$.  QED

---

The ring $\mathcal{O}$ which you describe is called the *absolute integral closure* of $R$ in the following paper:

> *Artin, M.*, [**On the joins of Hensel
> rings**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0001-8708(71)80007-5), Adv. Math. 7,
> 282-296 (1971).
> [ZBL0242.13021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0242.13021).

You can read a bit more about this on the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DCK) or in [this book by Swanson and Huneke](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eiswanso/book/index.html). Both the Stacks Project and [these notes of Swanson](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eiswanso/trieste.pdf) claim that the absolute integral closure has the following property: every monic polynomial in $\mathcal{O}[x]$ has a root in $\mathcal{O}$.

---

By the way, while I was looking for references, I also came across your construction in the following paper:

> *Enochs, Edgar*, [**Totally integrally
> closed rings**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2035868), Proc. Am. Math. Soc.
> 19, 701-706 (1968).
> [ZBL0157.08501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0157.08501).

Proposition 3 of this paper states that the ring you construct is *totally integrally closed*, which means that if $f \colon A \to \mathcal{O}$ is a ring homomorphism and $A \subseteq B$ is an integral extension, then $f$ extends to a homomorphism $g \colon B \to \mathcal{O}$. I am not sure whether total integral closure is equivalent to absolute integral closure. Perhaps someone else can enlighten us.